# почему не работает empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```html
<?
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
 
if (empty($login)) { echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=fail_try.php?id=1'></head></html>";}
else{


$login = $_POST['login'];
$login = stripslashes($login); $login = htmlspecialchars($login); $login = trim($login);

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$result3 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET login='$login' WHERE login='$old_login'");//обновляем в базе логин пользователя
if ($result3=='TRUE') {//если выполнено верно, то обновляем все сообщения, которые отправлены ему
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE messages SET author='$login' WHERE author='$old_login'");
$_SESSION['login'] = $login;//Обновляем логин в сессии
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) {
setcookie("login", $login, time()+9999999);//Обновляем логин в куках
}

$data = 1;}//отправляем пользователя назад

}
}
?>
```

когда вводу пустое поле то изменяет в mysql на пустое поле но при обновлении страницыменя пербрасывает на fail_try.php?id=1 что не так?

Comment: Так у Вас переменная $login не определена до вызова empty, выражение всегда будет true